# Dialogflow system.entity location: location.admin-area is not defined in online editor

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I use system entity @sys.location in an intent in a Dialogflow agent. In the fulfillment section, I have this function in online code editor:

```
function testLocation(agent) {
    //check object location
    console.log(' location is ' +  JSON.stringify(agent.parameters.location));
    if(agent.parameters.location.city) {

        //do smthing 
    }
    else if (agent.parameters.location.admin-area){
      agent.add(`this is not recognized ` +agent.parameters.location.admin-area); 
    }else{
     //....
    }
  }
```

Point is that I receive a warning sign in the editor saying 'area is not defined', but I can see its values from the Firebase Console :

```
{"country":"","city":"","admin-area":"Piemonte","business-name":"","street-address":"","zip-code":"","shortcut":"","island":"","subadmin-area":""}
```

Any clues?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're tripping over a JavaScript syntax issue.

The expression

```
agent.parameters.location.admin-area
```

is being evaluated as

```
agent.parameters.location.admin - area
```

that is to say `agent.parameters.location.admin` minus `area`, which is causing an error because, as the error says, the "area" attribute of "location" isn't defined.

In this, `agent.parameters.location` is an Object, and JavaScript provides two ways to access attributes of an Object

- You can use bracket notation `[expression]` where the expression inside the brackets should evaluate to the name of an attribute of the object. Usually this needs to be a string.
- In some cases, you can use dot notation `.name` where the name is the name of the property. But this assumes the name doesn't have characters used by other JavaScript syntax.

Note the difference between "expression" and "name". The first lets you use a variable with a string in it, or something else you've computed. The second requires you to hardcode it.

In your case, you can use bracket notation to get the value you want. So something like

```
agent.parameters.location["admin-area"]
```

should work.